# Export TrustedSendersAndDomains to csv using powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, exchange-server

Hi Stackoverflow community, this is my first time posting a question.

I'm also new to powershell but I was able to put together a small script based on other scripts I found and it kind of works.
My goal is to query all mailboxes and output a column with the user and one with the entry for their trustedsendersanddomains.
I would like it to repeat the user when the user has multiple entries and display none in case they don't have any. It would look something like this:

[csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRYht.png)

This is what I have. (for testing purposes I'm setting 3 actual users but the commented part works)

```
$Users = ("user1", "user2", "user3")
#$Users = Get-Mailbox | select -ExpandProperty Alias
$objfull = @()

Foreach ($User in $Users)
        {
         $Junk = Get-MailboxJunkEmailConfiguration $User
         $Emails = Get-MailboxJunkEmailConfiguration $User | select -ExpandProperty TrustedSendersAndDomains
         $obj = New-Object System.Object
              Foreach ($Email in $Emails)
                      {
                         $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty User $User
                         $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Trusted_Senders $Junk.TrustedSendersAndDomains
                         $objfull += $obj
                      }     
          
         }
$objfull | Export-Csv C:\Users\Leo\export.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

While it will throw error for users without entries this works in repeating the user, but the trusted sender output is the whole array and it's space separated, not comma.

This other one I was testing with will write to terminal the way I want the csv to be.

```
$Users = ("user1", "user2", "user3")
#$Users = Get-Mailbox | select -ExpandProperty Alias
$objfull = @()

Foreach ($User in $Users)
        {
         $Junk = Get-MailboxJunkEmailConfiguration $User
         $Emails = Get-MailboxJunkEmailConfiguration $User | select -ExpandProperty TrustedSendersAndDomains
         $obj = New-Object System.Object
              Foreach ($Email in $Emails)
                      {
                         Write-Host $Email, $User
                      }     
          
         }
#$objfull | Export-Csv C:\Users\Leo\export.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

I appreciate the help in advance!

Comment: Add the CSV as text in the question instead of an image. You can use a fixed width table here, like code, and it will be usable for people trying to help you.

Comment: TrustedSendersAndDomains is an array and as such needs to be converted something friendlier for CSV output. The default array delimiter in PowerShell when doing this is usually [space]. Something like `$Emails -join ";"` would be what you could play with.

Answer (score 0):

```
$Users = (Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited -RecipientTypeDetails UserMailbox).alias

$exports = Foreach ($user in $users)
{

Write-Host "Working on $user now!" -ForegroundColor Green

Get-MailboxJunkEmailConfiguration $user | Select-Object identity,enabled,trustedsendersanddomains}

$exports | ForEach-Object {

    
    $Is_enabled = $_.enabled
    $identity = $_.identity
    $trustedsendersanddomains = $_.trustedsendersanddomains

       
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        
        Is_Enabled = $Is_enabled
        Identity   = $identity
       Trustedsendersanddomains = $trustedsendersanddomains

        }
        } | Export-Csv ".\trustedsenderslist.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).